# Every choice of basis is equally natural?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ denote a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $\mathbb K$. Then I read:

In practice, there is typically no choice of basis which seems more natural than the other choices. To convince yourself of this, consider the case where $V$ is an arbitrary subspace of $\mathbb K^m$ for some $m > n$.

Why does considering it a subspace of a bigger space explain why no choice of basis is more natural than any other? (Especially if the bigger space is $\mathbb R^m$ it seems more natural to choose the standard basis)

Comment: Just because a vector space has a natural basis, that doesn't tell you how to get a natural basis for a subspace.

Comment: Given a matrix $(a_{ik})_{1\leq i\leq m, \ 1\leq k\leq n}$ the set of all $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ satisfying the system of equations $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}x_k=0\qquad(1\leq i\leq m)$$ is a subspace $V\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ having no distinguished basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point being made is that $\mathbb K^m$ has many different subspaces of dimension $n$ and in general there is no natural choice of a basis for such a subspace.

What would you say is a natural basis for the plane given by $x+y+z=0$ in $\mathbb R^3$?